# Converting to Chomsky normal form

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

Im having some problems with a qeuestion regarding converting a context free grammar to chomsky normal form.

I have 
        S -> abC | babS | de
        C -> aCa |b

I know what to do with the case of aCa and de and b but im not sure how to handle the abC case or the babS case. I believe that chomsky normal form is supposed to have outputs of only 2 characters. so with something like aCa you make and output aa and have A->a and create another nonterminal? X -> SA but I dont know how im supposed to handle the abC case or the babS case.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you studied how to convert a grammar to Chomsky to normal form?  It sounds like not.  So, I suggest you read up on this in Wikipedia or in your textbook....

Comment: I recommend that you read about how to convert a grammar into Chomsky normal form. There are standard techniques for doing so. For instance, they're most likely covered in your textbook. [Wikipedia also explains a procedure for converting any grammar to Chomsky normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Converting_a_grammar_to_Chomsky_Normal_Form). That should be sufficient to help you solve your exercise on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Let's work it out through the conversion algorithm given in 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Converting_a_grammar_to_Chomsky_Normal_Form).

**input:**
$S \to  abC \mid  babS \mid de$
$C\to aCa \mid b$

1. **Introduce** $S_0$:
   $S_0 \to S$
   $S \to  abC \mid  babS \mid de$
   $C\to aCa \mid b$
2. **remove $\epsilon$ rules:** there are no $\epsilon$ rules, so nothing changes.
3. **eliminate unit rules**: Originally, there are none, but we added one, namely $S_0\to S$. Since it's the only one, we'll deal with it later (after $S$ is already in CNF). This will be done by adding, for any rule $S\to V_iV_j$, the  rule $S_0 \to V_iV_j$. But let's first complete the conversion.
4. **replace all other rules into normal form**: we take each transition which is not in the correct form and replace it with $N\to V_iV_j$, introducing new non-terminals $V_1, V_2,...$ as needed:

   - $S\to ab C$ $\Longrightarrow$ $S\to V_1 C$ 
     setting $V_1 \to ab$. The new $V_1$ is not in CNF, but can easily be converted to CNF by re-defining it as $V_1\to AB$ with $A\to a$, $B\to b$.
   - $S\to babS$ $\Longrightarrow$ $S\to V_2S$ adding $V_2 \to bab$. Now $V_2$ is not in CNF, so we change it to $V_2 \to V_3B$ adding $V_3\to BA$. (skipping a trivial step here)
   - $S\to de$ is almost CNF. We change it to $S\to DE$ and add $E\to e$, and $D\to d$.
   - $C\to aCa$ $\Longrightarrow$ $C\to AV_4$ where $V_4 \to CA$.
   - $C \to b$ is already in CNF.

so we end up with:
$S_0 \to S$
$S\to V_1 C$
$S\to V_2S$
$S\to DE$
$C\to AV_4$
$C \to b$
$V_1 \to AB$
$V_2 \to V_3B$
$V_3 \to BA$
$V_4 \to CA$
and $A\to a$, $B\to b$, $D\to d$, $E\to e$.

Finally, we need to deal with the unit rule $S_0 \to S$. As said, we will replace the $S$ in the right-hand-side with the "content" of S. That is, we remove that unit rule and add instead:
$S_0 \to V_1C \mid V_2S \mid DE$.